# What kind of communication can I use in android app communicating to webserver?

Tags: android, web-applications

I'd like to make an app witch is virtual stock trading. So there is a client app and a web server. What kind of communication mechanism is better?

Comment: @MitchWheat you are wrong, the string can also have a ` ` space, or a tab or a newline character. It can be a loose string.

Comment: carrier pigeon has its advantages.

Comment: If you don't need the app to be native Android you could use html5 websockets and then it would automatically be cross platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try json or soap. Json is faster...

Answer (score 0):

[Spring for android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) is probably one of the best out of the box solutions.

It uses REST to communicate to the web server, assuming that's how your web server is exposed.  Other than that you could look at SOAP as a potential solution (SOAP vs REST is a massive debate and should be looked into separately).

It really depends more so on what your web server actually does, then work from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may try JSON , XML parsing.. Thats your wish..